# Custom Terms of Use Page before login to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, authentication

I am using MOSS with ADS. I want to display Terms of Use page before the user can login into SharePoint with two button i.e. "Accept","Decline".  If user select "Accept" he will be directed to sharepoint site, if not to our companies intranet front page. This will be applicable for the current session. ie. If the user has signed off, then it should prompt the terms of use again when user hits the MOSS site but once accepted user should not get this page again until he/she signs off.

Please advise.
Thank you

Comment: Did you find a solution?  If so please accept or post one please.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow one of the Approach below based on your requirement & Flexibility.

1. If you have AD Configured with the FBA, Make a copy of Login.aspx and save it as MyLogin.aspx & Edit the Login Control and insert your Terms & Conditions there,keep in a check box AND enable the login button only if I agree is checked.
2. Next is to have a control that is deployed to the Master Page, this control will not have a UI but it will check in the session to see if the user has agreed the Terms and condition if  yes it will redirect to the welcome page or the page user has requested else will navigate him to the Terms page until accepts.On Accept flag that information in session.
3. If you are using SharePoint 2010 you could use the Dialog framework to show a popup & get this done.

Comment: 1) I cannot use FBA because this is a Intranet site. 
2) I did have this idea about creating a session control to do this but I have no idea how to do this with SharePoint. Especially how to work with SharePoint session. Can you please provide any examples or links?
3) We don't have 2010 so this not an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom page in /_layouts which has your terms and conditions, along with the buttons for accept/decline.

Hitting the accept button will create a cookie for keeping track of whether or not the user has accepted the conditions for the current session.

Then, you could create a HttpModule which intercepts all requests to the SharePoint site. If the cookie is present, do nothing (ie let the user access the requested page), otherwise redirect the browser to the custom accept/decline page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this fairly easily.  If you dont care about them accepting or denying it, then just use this redirect module http://httpcode.s3.amazonaws.com/httpcode.Redirect.wsp to redirect them once to the page.  You can tell this module to do it once.  If you need to verify that they accept/decline, you will need to add all the people to a new group, and then on accepting, remove them from that group.  That way they will always be directed to the new page.

Hope this helps